# "Failed - No File" when trying to download a PDF in Angular 6 project

Tags: angular

So, here I've got a locally stored file named "real-pdf-15445563885226.pdf" in the `show-report component`

[image: show-report files showing PDF and component]

I'm trying to reference a download to the PDF using an HTML tag inside of the `show-report.component.html`:
`<a href="real-pdf-1544563885226.pdf" download>PDF</a>`

It is a real PDF file, if I go double click on the file manually I can see it display and it's real. However, when I go to my application on: http://localhost:4200/report (name of route in which it lives), and click on the link, I get a "Failed - No File" error.

[image: Failed - No File picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the pdf in the assets folder (default location supplied by Angular cli), or if you have another dedicated public folder for your static assets, put it there.

Comment: Okay, I moved the PDF to the assets folder, and changed the html to: <a href="src\assets\real-pdf-1544563885226.pdf" download>PDF</a> (relative path), and still the same error.

Comment: Angular is compiling everything and moving all code and assets into your public or dist folder. That is where you reference it. Probably just `/assets/pdf.pdf`.

Comment: Its my pleasure!

Comment: Hey, Ben. I'm having a bit more trouble. When I'm in production mode (after I've ran ng build --prod), adding more reports to the assets folder doesn't work anymore. I understand that the assets folder isn't in use anymore. So, do you know any way I can have a dynamic folder to upload reports (maybe on the backend) to be used in production without having to upload to an assets folder?

Comment: How are you serving your application? With Express? What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185097/discussion-between-happy-sheep-and-ben-steward).

Comment: Sorry, on vacation, not interested in the commitment. Why not post the necessary information so myself (and many other devs!) can weigh in? Also, don't forget to google and trial and error!

Comment: I just did that because stack overflow says "Please avoid extended discussions in commends. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" and i hit yes. I use Express, file structure can be seen on my github which can be found here: https://github.com/YungSheep/Civil-Grand-Jury

Comment: No problem, I didn’t realize SO did that. Are you accounting for the fact that your PDFs are in a specific folder?